# "The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, null"

Tags: java

Why eclipse say :

> "The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, null"

At the if statement ? Why is inauthorized to write it ?

```
Object max;
double a1;
double a2;

if ((max != null && a1 > a2) ¦¦ max == null)
     // Something
```

Comment: What is this thing `¦¦`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: i think a weirdly formatted ||

Comment: Are you sure `max` is an `Object`?

Comment: I've changed ¦¦ to || and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make your code to compile, you just have to initialize the variables before, and get rid of this `¦¦` - I think you wanted to use OR which is `||`

```
Object max = null;
double a1 = 0;
double a2 = 0;

if ((max != null && a1 > a2) || max == null){}
```

Comment: Initializing the variable is not the problem.

Comment: I think it is. Code is not compiling without initializing the variables.

Comment: I'm confused.. then what's this `boolean` error he's getting?

Comment: @MarounMaroun he's probably initializing them in some part of code he's not posting

Comment: @MarounMaroun Got the same error with that `¦¦`, After `||`  everything fine, In short ,eclipse confused :)

Comment: @eis That's what I thought.. otherwise, `boolean` cannot appear in the error message.

Comment: Ahahahaha ! really sorry ! I have changed my keyboard and I have think it's a pipe ! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

Just tested, Everything fine, other than that  mysterious `¦¦` ,use `||`

```
Object max = null;
        double a1 = 0;
        double a2 = 0;

        if ((max != null && a1 > a2) || max == null){

        }
```

Eclipse just confused and saying

```
The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, null


if ( (max != null && a1 > a2)  ¦¦ max == null  ){
     ........^........(boolean) , ..null....... (treating that ¦¦ as comma)
        }
```